# posting file input type to a form

Tags: asp.net, html, request

First I must say that my problem happens when I'm trying to post to another form.

I have 3 controls in a form:
1. text input named "text1".
2. file input named "file1".
3. submit input.

the form itself have a post method to another page.
in the page load of the posted page I'm using Request["text1"] which gives me the text of "text1". when I'm Request["file1"] I get nothing.

help?

Comment: can you explain the type of your control? is it asp.net control or html?

Comment: html: 
    <form id="f1" name="f1" runat="server" method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="textOfUser"/>
        <input type="file" id="myFile" runat="server"/>
        <input type="submit&

Answer (score 2):

You need *enctype="multipart/form-data"* in your opening form tag.

```
<form method="post" action="somepage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

If that doesn't help, [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com) have an article on this very topic:

#### [Uploading in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140211/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/091201-1.shtml)

Comment: i have it and it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Request["file1"] is not a string, it's a file, so you can't peek inside it that way. How it is handled will depend on the server-size platform you're using.

Comment: in the code behind of the same page - you're correct, but this is the way i get it from another asp.net page.